# Mongoose: Is relationship using virtuals a good practice?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In mongodb(mongoose) & NodeJS(express) stack, i know that one to many relationships generally looks like this: (simplified example)

```js
const { Schema } = require("mongoose");

const DB = require("../db");

const companySchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, default: "" },
  contacts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "contacts" }],
});

const contactSchema = new Schema({
  fullName: { type: String, default: "" },
  number: { type: String },
  company: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "companies" },
});

const Company = DB.model("companies", companySchema);
const Contact = DB.model("contacts", contactSchema);

module.exports = {Company,Contact};
```

I found out that my workplace always use virtuals for one to many relationship like this:

```js
const { Schema } = require("mongoose");

const DB = require("../db");

const companySchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, default: "" },
});
companySchema.virtual("contacts", {
  ref: "contacts",
  localField: "_id",
  foreignField: "company",
});

const contactSchema = new Schema({
  fullName: { type: String, default: "" },
  number: { type: String },
  company: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "companies_with_virtuals" },
});

const VirtualContact = DB.model("contacts", contactSchema);
const CompanyWithVirtuals = DB.model("companies", companySchema);

module.exports = {VirtualContact,CompanyWithVirtuals};
```

As far as i know, the pros of using virtuals is that i dont need to update Company everytime i post a new Contact. I just want to know what are the cons of using it, when to use it, and is it actually a good practice?

Im still a junior developer, any insight are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mongoose, a virtual is a property that is not stored in MongoDB. Virtuals are typically used for computed properties on documents.

Since a virtual doesn't store in MongoDB, it doesn't use for one to many relationships in the aspect of designing a database.

As for the example mentioned above, you can consider 2 methods:

1. Storing Contact Ref Id into Company.Contracts ( as you write in the first section )
2. SubDocument

```
    const childSchema = new Schema({name: string});
    const parentScehma = new Schema ({
       children: [childSchema], // * Array of SubDocuments
       child: childSchema, // * Singe nested SubDocument
    });
```

While using NoSQL DB, it's important to think if your access pattern first, then the relation of each collection. This is a very common mistake I encountered, no matter how experienced the developer is.
To choose the correct method to design your schema :

1. Does child schema always comes with parent schema?
2. Does update child schema very often happen?
3. Does child schema within parent schema could grow unlimited?

Hope this helps, you can reference mongoose's official document about Virtual and SubDocuments

[Mongoose v7.0.1 Subdcouments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html.)
[Monngose v7.0.1 Mongoose Virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html)